# How can I unset a key by key name within all subarrays in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array that looks somewhat like this: `array("a"=>array("a"=>"b"), "b"=>array("a"=>"d"))`.
I would like to unset all vars with the key "a" within the array and it sub-arrays. Assume that the data's structure is unknown. All I want is that if the key "a" exists somewhere within the parent array or it sons - it'll be unset. Is it possible?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708860/php-recursively-unset-array-keys-if-match

Comment: Yap, Babiker's link does have what you want. save your time and just go there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function unsetKey (&$array, $key) {
  foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    if (is_array($v))
      unsetKey($array[$k], $key);
  if (isset($array[$key])) unset(array[$key]);
}
```

That should do it.