# Removing an element from a nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Am working on a Laravel application whereby I have an associative array that am to pass to an API endpoint, Before posting to the API, **I want to delete the img key together with its value** . I have tried to use unset function but it is not removing the img key

**Array where I want to remove the image property**

```
 $a[] = [
  0 => array:4 [
    "name" => "Martoo nnn"
    "relationship" => "Spouse"
    "dob" => "2001-02-03"
    "img" => "img.png"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "name" => "sdsdsd sdsdsd"
    "relationship" => "Child"
    "dob" => "2019-04-04"
    "img" => "img1.png"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "name" => "sdsdsd sddds"
    "relationship" => "Child"
    "dob" => "2019-04-05"
    "img" => "img2.png"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "name" => "dssdsd dsdsd"
    "relationship" => "Child"
    "dob" => "2019-04-02"
    "img" => "img3.png"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [
    "name" => "dssdsd dssdsd"
    "relationship" => "Child"
    "dob" => "2019-04-04"
    "img" => "img4.png"
  ]
];
```

**Unset method**

```
$array = $a;
unset($array['img']);

//dd($a);
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708860/php-recursively-unset-array-keys-if-match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) { // & defines changes will be made @ value itself
    unset($value['img']);
}
```

And Yes, I don't understand why you initialised `$a` as `$a[]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array_filter($a, function($k) {
    return $k != 'img';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

and pass this new array

Comment: Are you sure about this? Will this work in the nested array that is given in the question?